# Шаблон и автоматическое выведение типов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Написал вспомогательный шаблонный метод класса с автоматическим выведением типа:

```
template<size_t TField, class TType = typename std::tuple_element<TField, Interface::Config::_Data>::type>
void MapField(const std::string& key, const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const TType&)>& pt = std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const TType&)>()){
     auto value = _store.Get<TField>();
     if (pt){
        _obj->set(key, pt(value));
     }
     else{
        _obj->set(key, value);
     }
}
```

При автоматическом выведении не компилирует, явно указываю тип компилит. ***gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)***

```
Object::Ptr Interface::Writer::Write(){
    _obj.assign(new Object);
    MapField<Interface::Config::Name>("name");
    MapField<Interface::Config::DNS>("dns");
    MapField<Interface::Config::DHCP>("dhcp");
    MapField<Interface::Config::MAC>("mac");

    auto lambda = std::bind(&Interface::Writer::ConvertAddr, *this, std::placeholders::_1);

    MapField<Interface::Config::IPv4, Poco::Net::IPAddress>("address", lambda); //компилируется
    //обращение к полю кортежа Poco::Net::IPAddress
    MapField<Interface::Config::Mask>("netmask", lambda); //не работает 
    //обращение к полю кортежа Poco::Net::IPAddress
    MapField<Interface::Config::Gateway>("gateway", lambda); //не работает

    return _obj;
}
```

PS

- Name, DNS, DHCP, IPv4, Mask ... - enum
- Interface::Config::_Data - std::tuple

Ошибки:

```
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp: In member function 'Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr Interface::Writer::Write()':
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:22:56: error: no matching function for call to 'Interface::Writer::MapField(const char [8], std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<Poco::Dynamic::Var (Interface::Writer::*)(const Poco::Net::IPAddress&)>(Interface::Writer, std::_Placeholder<1>)>&)'
     MapField<Interface::Config::Mask>("netmask", lambda); //не работает
                                                        ^
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:22:56: note: candidate is:
In file included from ../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:1:0:
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/include/Interface/Writer.h:17:10: note: template<long unsigned int TField, class TType> void Interface::Writer::MapField(const string&, const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var(const TType&)>&)
     void MapField(const std::string& key, const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const TType&)>& pt = std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const TType&)>()){
          ^
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/include/Interface/Writer.h:17:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:22:56: note:   'std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<Poco::Dynamic::Var (Interface::Writer::*)(const Poco::Net::IPAddress&)>(Interface::Writer, std::_Placeholder<1>)>' is not derived from 'const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var(const TType&)>'
     MapField<Interface::Config::Mask>("netmask", lambda); //не работает
                                                        ^
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:23:59: error: no matching function for call to 'Interface::Writer::MapField(const char [8], std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<Poco::Dynamic::Var (Interface::Writer::*)(const Poco::Net::IPAddress&)>(Interface::Writer, std::_Placeholder<1>)>&)'
     MapField<Interface::Config::Gateway>("gateway", lambda); //не работает
                                                           ^
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:23:59: note: candidate is:
In file included from ../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:1:0:
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/include/Interface/Writer.h:17:10: note: template<long unsigned int TField, class TType> void Interface::Writer::MapField(const string&, const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var(const TType&)>&)
     void MapField(const std::string& key, const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const TType&)>& pt = std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const TType&)>()){
          ^
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/include/Interface/Writer.h:17:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../../../NetworkManager/InterfaceLib/Interface/src/Writer.cpp:23:59: note:   'std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<Poco::Dynamic::Var (Interface::Writer::*)(const Poco::Net::IPAddress&)>(Interface::Writer, std::_Placeholder<1>)>' is not derived from 'const std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var(const TType&)>'
     MapField<Interface::Config::Gateway>("gateway", lambda); //не работает
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

упростил до двух методов:

```
template<size_t TField>
void MapField(const char* key){
       auto value = _store.Get<TField>();
       _obj->set(key, value);
}

template<
    size_t TField,
    class TCallback = typename std::function<Poco::Dynamic::Var (const typename std::tuple_element<TField, Interface::Config::_Data>::type&)>
>
void MapField(const char* key, TCallback clbck){
    auto value = clbck(_store.Get<TField>());
    _obj->set(key, value);
}
```